# how to upload multiple files inside mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file-upload

Hello friends I am new in nodejs and mongodb. Is it possible to upload multiple files inside single mongodb doc with other information.

Comment: If multiple file upload is not possible then how to design our doc structure

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `BSON` (Binary JSON) to store files in MongoDB collections. However, BSON has a limit of `16MB`. If you are planning to store files bigger than that, consider [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/)

You can write files to MongoDB like so in Node.js:

```
var Binary = require(‘mongodb’).Binary;
//Read the file that you want to store
var file_data = fs.readFileSync(file_path);
var db_doc = {};
db_doc.file_data= Binary(file_data);

var my_collection = db.collection(‘files’);
my_collection.insert(db_doc, function(err, result){
//more code..
....
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my question was how to store multiple files within same doc of mongodb with other user data